# Downloading email attachment in android program?

Tags: android, email-attachments

I have searched a lot but could not find any solution. So I am asking question here. Is there any way to download email attachment in android program. Kindly help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806644/downloading-gmail-attachment-in-android-program
I have tried the code given in this link but this code give me errors. and I don't know how to start.

Comment: You should add the code to your post and show at which point errors occur (and also what errors)

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872991/android-correctly-downloading-saving-an-email-attachement)